# AutoItV3 Window Info Tool unable to detect the Installer Window

Tags: windows-7, autoit, robotframework, installanywhere

Am totally new to RobotFrameWork, am trying to automate a installer using RobotFramework--AutoItLibrary. But when am trying to use AutoItV3 window Info tool its unable to give the information about the window(i.e installer GUI). It only gives the information of GUI Title & Class - "SunAwtFrame". 
This installer is developed using "InstallAnyWhere -- Tool" 
Can any one help me in sorting out this issue.

Comment: Have a look whether there are silent install options. If not, and Autoit WIndow Info Tool deosn't help, then be beware of this: you can use ControlCommands without the exact ControlID. Just skip that parameter and only use Title and Name and then "". Third way would be using Send commands and MouseClick and so an while using BlockInput to secure the commands.

Comment: Thank you, i guess i have to try out your inputs